# ScrollView items in two Equal Columns React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, layout, expo, native

below code works fine where there are only two elements in ScrollView container.
but if there are more items they remain in a single row despite giving them a flex: wrap property

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default class GridView extends Component {

   render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button title="Button 1"/>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button title="Button 2"/>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button title="Button 1"/>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button title="Button 2"/>
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: 10,
        gap: 10,
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        flex: 1,
    }
});
```

https://snack.expo.dev/OxHKR0PQT

Comment: are you want to create a grid view?

Answer (score 0):

Remove "flex: 1" from buttonContainer and change styles of container according to below code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default class GridView extends Component {

   render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button title="Button 1"/>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button title="Button 2"/>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button title="Button 1"/>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button title="Button 2"/>
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 10,
        gap: 10,
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        flexBasis: '40%,
    }
});
```

Comment: I did that but still Two equal columns layout is not being formed. you can test on Expo link

Comment: Please use this style-
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: 10,
        gap: 10,
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        flexBasis: '40%'
    }
});

Comment: I updated the above my code, you can check. it will work.. You need to add flexBasis: '40%' in buttonContainer style

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to do something like this,

- pass all the buttons to GridView component from the parent component
- inside the Gridview transform your buttons array to something like this.

  ```
   const allButtons = [["button_1", "button_2"], ["button_3", "button_4"]];
  ```

above you have paired two buttons into subarrays. Then do something like below,

```
     export default class GridView extends Component {
    
       render() {
            return (
                <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
                  {allButtons.map(buttonRow => <ButtonRow row={buttonRow}/>)}
                </ScrollView>
            );
        }
    }
    
    const ButtonRow = (props) => {
    
    return (
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    {props.row.map(buttonTitle => <Button title={buttonTitle}/>)}
    </View>
    )

}
```